# gulp src not exclude all files from a folder

Tags: gulp

I've created 2 task, *'compileApp'* and *'compileAppDeploy'*. Basically, they are similar just *compileAppDeploy* minify code to be deployed.

Independently both task runs well, although if *compileAppDeploy* runs first then *compileApp* concat minified code from **dist** folder

Unsuccessfully I've tried several paths combinations. Although if I set below path then *javaScriptMinified.js* will be removed but *htmlAngularMinified.js* will be concated.

```
'!./app/dist/*.js
```

**dir structure**

```
   +root
      +app
         +dist    -> Exclude
           -javaScriptMinified.js  -> after run compileAppDeploy task
           -htmlAngularMinified.js  -> after run compileAppDeploy task
         +filters -> Include
         +l10n    -> Exclude
         +components -> Include 
         -app.js     -> Include
      +css
      -gulpfile.js
      -index.html
      -package.json
```

**compileApp**

```
gulp.task('compileApp', function() {

return gulp.src(['./app/app.js','./app/**/*.js','!./app/dist/'])
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler : onError}))
    .pipe(concat('LoginPortal.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/' ));

});
```

**compileAppDeploy**

```
gulp.task('compileAppDeploy', function( version ) {

return gulp.src(['./app/app.js','./app/**/*.js','!./app/dist/'])
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler : onError}))
    .pipe(stripDebug())
    .pipe(uglify({
        warnings : false
    }))
    .pipe(replace('app/l10n' ,'' + version + '/l10n'))
    .pipe(concat('LoginPortal' + version + '.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/dist/' + version + '/' ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unsuccessfully I've tried several paths combinations. Although if I set below path then *javaScriptMinified.js* will be removed but *htmlAngularMinified.js* will be concated.
>
> ```
> '!./app/dist/*.js
> ```

You only exclude files directly in `./app/dist/`, not in subdirectories. That probably means that `htmlAngularMinified.js` is in a subdirectory while `javaScriptMinified.js` is not.

You need to exclude `.js` files from all directory levels: `!./app/dist/**/*.js`

You wouldn't have to worry about any of that if you just used a proper directory structure. Putting your distribution directory inside your source directory is just a terrible idea. Instead of this structure:

```
+root
   +app
      +dist
```

Use the following structure:

```
+root
   +app
   +dist
```

Then in your `compileAppDeploy` you can just do this:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/' + version + '/' ));
```

And you don't have to worry about excluding the `dist` dir, because it's no longer below `./app`.